Change starting directory in ubuntu
I have installed ubuntu because my online course is teaching me how to use it, only problem is when i load it up i start out in root@LAPTOP-6B3Q3GTR: ~#. everytime he loads up it says colt@colsteele599: ~$
The way my teacher installed in was very long but that video was made a while ago so all i had to do was type in a command and it installed it for me,everytime he starts his up its loaded into his home folder (/home/teachername)
I am EXTREMELY new to this whole terminal thing i just barely learned pwd, ls, and cd. I have no idea what im doing and all the youtube videos are pretty old. This is august 2024 and now you can change settings through the terminal instead of using a json file.
Can anybody show me how when i start it up i am automatically in my /home/user file? Like i said im extremely fresh i know nothing and an explanation would propell me even further, Thanks a lot!
my username is vschultz03
there is a starting directory setting and i have tried setting it to
/home,/vschultz03, ~ /home
none of these worked

Did you try /home/vschultz03 (no comma) in your "settings"?

yes i did sorry, the comma was to seperate the different things i tried, i did not include a comma in any of those commands

You are logged in as root (the superuser). You can see that from the shell prompt, as it says "root" at the front and ends with a # rather than with a $. So you are in root's home directory.
You say "when i load it up". What exactly do you mean by that? When you switch on the machine? When you log in? Or something else?
It may be that your machine is set to boot into root, or into single-user mode.

When i load it up mean when i open terminal which automatically loads ubuntu. I have found a temporary fix which is typing login and typing my login details then i get exaxctly what my teacher is getting, however is there a way for when ubuntu is started for it to automatically login?

Did you actually install Ubuntu - or did you install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? if the latter, see How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10

ah, WSL might explain the JSON configuration comment, which also confused me.
